# Does savant people have an Higher/Lower Working Memory?

Tags: working-memory, savant-syndrome

I have searched a lot about the Working Memory Capacity
and savant or eidetic people but I can´t find a paper which
describes a correlation between savant/eidetic people and
the working memory capacity.

Does anyone knows a paper or a experiment where such a correlation is checked/proofed ?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15652316 mentions only studies with autism (in general) and since this is a paper on high-functioning autism, I doubt more specific results/knowledge existed till then (still the paper is a decade old now) or they would have mentioned it. Also the results for autism in general were mixed, some research found lower working memory others found no difference from controls.

Comment: that´s similar what I found, I think the problem is that the working memory is in coherence with different types of attention which are not all known yet... but thanks for ur help =)